# Scaling entire scene with light maintaining correct shadows - How?

Tags: lighting

I need to scale the entire scene up by a lot because  without know I had all ther dimensions wrong. When I scale up the scene, the like moves far away and doesn't increase brightness. This means that if there is no way to make it grow proportionally, I need to relight the scene. I rather find a simple way to do that as it is a VFX shot and I matched the sunlight of the live action footage with an area light. How can I fix this?

Comment: just to let you know the light`s brightness level doesn`t increase when you scale it up

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can calculate how much I need to increase it to have the same exact result?

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible

Comment: OK, I'm going crazy now lol It scales properly but even if I set the light's power from 2000 W to 10.000 W I can't see any shadows. I also increased the size of the area light with no result.

https://imgur.com/a/AivuWIG

I uploaded a screen of the unscaled version which has the shadow and one of the scaled scene that lost the shadow.

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is shadow catcher and shadow pass so you can combine the 3d with real footage